# Time series / state space model conceptual

Tags: time, model, time-series, state, space

I want to predict a value. I have a time series as well as a bunch of other time series that may be interesting to use to augment the prediction.

Someone is arguing with me that it is the same thing to find the correlation between 2 non stationary time series and finding the correlation when making both stationary by some sort of differencing. Their logic is that a state space model doesn't care.

Isn't the whole idea of regression to exploit correlations to predict values? Doesn't there have to exist a correlation to incorporate an explanation of variance in the data and not increase the variance in the predictions? Also, I am 100% convinced that finding the correlation between two non stationary time series without doing anything is wrong.... And you'll end up with correlations to time and not the variables themselves.

Any input is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the models you're employing later on. You say that there has to exist a correlation or else the variance in the predictions will increase. That might hold for some models. Rather, I'd recommend you to go for models that have some model-election in themselves.

Think of LASSO, for example, that gives sparse vectors for the coefficients. Or think of a model that allows you to calculate Variable Importance and base your decisions on that outcome.

Second, let's do some math:

Correlation original = E[X(t)*Y(t)]

Correlation differencing = E[(X(t)-X(t-1))*(Y(t)-Y(t-1))] = E[X(t)Y(t)] + E[X(t-1)Y(t)] + E[X(t-1)Y(t-1)] + E[X(t)Y(t-1)]

If you assume that one time series is not correlated with the other time-series previous sample, then this reduces to
 = E[X(t)Y(t)] + E[X(t-1)Y(t-1)]

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was talking about the increase of variance when forcing a variable into a model and not doing any sort of checking for significant and explanation of variance in the data. You can't just throw in variables... even if there exists a certain correlation and hope for the best.
Is my reasoning correct for why you wouldn't calculate correlation between two time series without making them stationary first? You're finding a correlation to time/a common or inverse trend? I mean any time series that's drifting up will have an extreme correlation to any increasing function